# Sets with one accumulation point

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

Are there any more examples of sets in $\mathbb R$ that have one accumulation point apart from convergent sequences? I can´t think of any

Answer (score 2):

The set $$A=\Bbb Z\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$ has only $0$ as an accumulation point, but it is not homeomorphic to a convergent sequence together with its limit point: the latter is compact, and $A$ is not.

Comment: And if we ask for a bounded set that has one accumulation point?

Comment: @user128422: Then it will be homeomorphic to a sequence together with its limit point; proving that is a nice little exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sequence :

$u_{2n}=n$ and $u_{2n+1}=0$.

It diverges and its only accumulation point is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Just find a sequence that has multiple sub-sequential limits (1), or has at least one sub-sequential limit and is unbounded (2). For example of case (1):

$$a_n = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} \quad \text{ if } n \text{ is even}.\\
1+ \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{ if } n \text{ is odd}.
\end{cases}$$

For an example of case(2), replace $1+ \frac{1}{n}$ with $n$.